# CoreGraphics touch custom shape

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, cgcontext

I have a UIView subclass that draws a circle inside its drawRect:rect method. Now I want to react when the user touches the circle (not the view).

My idea was to get the CGPoint of the touch and ask CGContext if there is something.
Is there a way to check whether there is a fill or stroke? Or can I access the color at this point to see if it is opaque?

I think this must be possible because graphics get drawn to the screen so the system can do it somehow in a low level mechanism..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CGBitmapContextCreate()` to create a bitmap context and draw your image in it.

In bitmap context you can access individual pixels and check what color they are in the form of RGBA.